# Whole class @MainActor or just one function?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, data-binding, concurrency

I have the following code:

```
/* @MainActor */ class Locator : NSObject, ObservableObject
{
    private let locationManager: CLLocationManager
    private var authorizationContinuation: CheckedContinuation<CLAuthorizationStatus, Never>?

    @Published var authorizationStatus: CLAuthorizationStatus
    @Published var location: CLLocation?
    @Published var error: Error?

    override init()
    {
        locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        authorizationStatus = locationManager.authorizationStatus

        super.init()

        locationManager.delegate = self
    }

    /* @MainActor */ func checkAuthorizationStatus() async -> CLAuthorizationStatus
    {
        let status = locationManager.authorizationStatus
        if status == .notDetermined
        {
            return await withCheckedContinuation
            { continuation in
                authorizationContinuation = continuation

                locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
            }
        }
        else
        {
            authorizationStatus = status <=== WARNING

            return status
        }
    }
}

extension Locator : CLLocationManagerDelegate
{
    func locationManagerDidChangeAuthorization(_ manager: CLLocationManager)
    {
        authorizationStatus = manager.authorizationStatus

        authorizationContinuation?.resume(returning: authorizationStatus)
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error)
    {
        print(error)
        
        self.error = error
        location = nil
    }
}
```

Without either making the whole class or `checkAuthorizationStatus()` `@MainActor`, I get the following run-time warning:

> Publishing changes from background threads is not allowed; make sure
> to publish values from the main thread (via operators like
> receive(on:))

What would be your considerations for choosing to make the whole class `@MainActor` or just the function/'part' that needs it, in this case and in general?

EDIT: To satisfy people that vote to close this questions because it's seems based on opinion: Is there in the above code any run-time difference between the two options?

Comment: If the purpose of the class is to update a View you should put it on the class

Comment: @loremipsum Yes, the `@Published` properties are observed by SwiftUI view(s).

Comment: Then put it on the class there is no reason it should be on the function

Comment: @loremipsum I'd like to understand your thinking behind this. Would you be willing to share?

Comment: There isn’t much to it. UI needs to be updated on the MainActor or you get the publishing changes in the background warning. If the purpose of the class is to update UI it should be wrapped with MainActor. Why just wrap a function?

Comment: In general, if the sole purpose of the class is to publish properties for updating the UI, then it is a prime candidate to mark the whole class as `@MainActor`. It is doubly true in this case, as `CLLocationManager` needs a thread with a runloop, such as the main thread. See the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager).

Comment: @Rob Thanks for that valuable addition.  The documentation indeed reads: `Core Location calls the methods of your delegate object using the RunLoop of the thread on which you initialized the CLLocationManager object. That thread must itself have an active RunLoop, like the one found in your app’s main thread.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UI needs to be updated on the `MainActor` or you get the “publishing changes in the background warning”. If the purpose of the `class` is to update UI it should be wrapped with `MainActor`.